# Unneeded spacing in TikZ graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) node (A) [label=A] {}
        -- ++(60:2.0cm) node (B) {}
        -- ++(120:2.0cm) node (C) [label=C] {}
        -- ++(180:2.0cm) node (D) {}
        -- ++(240:2.0cm) node (D) {}
        -- ++(300:2.0cm) node (E) {}
        -- cycle{};
     \draw (A) -- ++ (-30:1cm) node (A1){}
     -- ++(-30:1cm) node (A2){}
     -- ++(60:2cm) node (B2){}
     -- ++(150:1cm) node (B1){}
     -- (B) -- cycle;   
     \draw (B1) -- (A1);
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

gives an unexpected spacing between node (A) and its repetition (I want to obtain a connected graph). How to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Just use `coordinate` instead of `node {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `coordinate` instead of `node {}` with its `inner width`, ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw (0,0) coordinate[label=A] (A)
        -- ++(60:2.0cm) coordinate (B)
        -- ++(120:2.0cm) coordinate[label=C] (C)
        -- ++(180:2.0cm) coordinate (D)
        -- ++(240:2.0cm) coordinate (D)
        -- ++(300:2.0cm) coordinate (E)
        -- cycle{};
     \draw (A) -- ++ (-30:1cm) coordinate (A1)
     -- ++(-30:1cm) coordinate (A2)
     -- ++(60:2cm) coordinate (B2)
     -- ++(150:1cm) coordinate (B1)
     -- (B) -- cycle;
     \draw (B1) -- (A1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Certainly +1, but could you explain the source of differences, please?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke A `coordinate` is more or less just a point, whereas a node has a dimension (`inner sep`, ...) and several anchor points. Nodes are connected from the outer side. Or you have to specify the anchor point explicitly, e.g. `A.center`.